# group records by adjacent values

Tags: r, data.table

I have a set of event records, with each event having `start` and `stop` value. I want to group all "adjacent" records, i.e. those with `start` being close enough to the `stop` of the previous record (say, difference not more than 20). For example:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- fread('
id subject event start stop
 1 subjA   yes      1     5
 2 subjA   yes     10    20
 3 subjA   no
 4 subjA   yes     21    30
 5 subjA   yes     90    99
 6 subjB   yes      1     5
', fill=T)
```

in this example, records 1, 2, and 4 should be group 1, while record 5 should fall into the next group because it's too far (`start`=90, previous `stop`=30) from the previous group. Here's how I do it now:

```
dt1[event=='yes', diff:=(start-shift(stop)), by=subject]
dt1[event=='yes' & (is.na(diff) | diff>20), grp1:=seq_len(.N), by=subject]
dt1[event=='yes', grp1:=ifelse(is.na(grp1),shift(grp1),grp1), by=subject]
dt1[event=='yes', grp1:=zoo::na.locf(grp1), by=subject]
dt1
```

It works but looks kinda ugly, and involves a function from another package (`zoo::na.locf()`, or `tidyr::fill()`). Any suggestions to make it simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this with `cumsum` :

```
library(data.table)

dt1[event == 'yes',diff := cumsum(start-shift(stop, fill = 0) > 20) + 1, subject]
dt1

#   id subject event start stop diff
#1:  1   subjA   yes     1    5    1
#2:  2   subjA   yes    10   20    1
#3:  3   subjA    no    NA   NA   NA
#4:  4   subjA   yes    21   30    1
#5:  5   subjA   yes    90   99    2
#6:  6   subjB   yes     1    5    1
```